# Running Wiremock in HTTPS mode with Keystore

Tags: https, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I am trying to create an HTTPS mocks using wiremock to test an external call.

Initially I tried to run the wiremock by providing the --https-port tag and set it as 8443. I was able to access localhost:8443/__admins in this case. But when I tried to hit the mock URL from my service, I was getting

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

So I created a JKS file following the steps provided in http://www.tecraf.com/post/my-first-post/ but when I am running the wiremock with the command

```
java -jar wiremock-standalone-2.26.0.jar --https-port 8443 --https-keystore mykeystore.jks --keystore-password password
```

I am not able to access localhost:8443/__admins

Is there something that I am missing.

Thanks in advance

Update: I was able to fix the issue by updating the Wiremock version to 2.33.2

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://localhost:8443/__admins.

but if you use postman to do this. there still occurs a problem.
Unable to verify the first certificate